# Include the whole post, not only summary. Jekyll

Tags: jekyll

I have a very noob question. I want to create a page, where will be presented all posts from some category. I understand, that I should write some {% include %} tag, but I could not understand which.
I have:

```
{% for post in site.posts %}

<!-- check if post comes from one of page categories-->
  {% assign PostAndPageCategories= page.categories | concat: post.categories %}
  {% capture all_cat %}{{ PostAndPageCategories | join: "," }}{% endcapture %}
  {% capture unique_cat %}{{ PostAndPageCategories |uniq | join: "," }}{% endcapture %}

  {% if all_cat != unique_cat %} 
  <!-- END check if post comes from one of page categories-->
 {% include archive-single.html %}
  {% endif %}

{% endfor %}
```

Obviously, this code shows me posts with teasers, but I need to display the whole post.

How should I change line `{% include archive-single.html %}`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found `{{post.content}}` instead of `{% include archive-single.html %}` work fine for me.